# Bitbucket raw access token expiration

Tags: token, bitbucket

In Bitbucket, you can publicly access files in a private repo via `https://bytebucket.org/username/repo/raw/sha/filename?token=sometoken`.
The link (including `sometoken`) can be generated by clicking the the `Raw` button in Bitbucket's file view.

I want to serve images in a wiki from this repository. Will this token ever expire?